# SQL Update/Insert Primary Key doesn't come along

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a library project in C# using MVC. While trying to update my 'borrower' table, the PersonId gets the value null. I'm quite new to programming so I don't know how much info to post. I put the code for save/update below. And also the constructor. I've tried the SQL questions in the database and they seem to be working.

```
    public Borrower(string firstname, string lastname, string address, string telno)
    {
        this._FirstName = firstname;
        this._LastName = lastname;
        this._Address = address;
        this._Telno = telno;
    }

    public Borrower() { }

    private int _CategoryId;

    private string _PersonId,
        _FirstName,
        _LastName,
        _Address,
        _Telno;

    public int CategoryId
    {
        get { return (int)this._CategoryId; }
        set { this._CategoryId = value; }
    }
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return this._FirstName; }
        set { this._FirstName = value; }
    }
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return this._LastName; }
        set { this._LastName = value; }
    }
    [Display(Name = "Person nr")]
    public string PersonId
    {
        get { return this._PersonId; }
        set { this._PersonId = value; }
    }
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address
    {
        get { return this._Address; }
        set { this._Address = value; }
    }
    [Display(Name = "Telno")]
    public string Telno
    {
        get { return this._Telno; }
        set { this._Telno = value; }
    }

    public int save()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Settings.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd;
        int retVal = -1;
        bool existing;
        if (this._PersonId != null)
        {
            existing = false;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BORROWER (PersonId, FirstName, LastName, Address, Telno, CategoryId) VALUES ('" + this._PersonId + "','" + this._FirstName + "','" + this._LastName + "','" + this._Address + "','" + this._Telno + "'," + _CategoryId + ");", con);
        }
        else
        {
            existing = true;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE BORROWER set FirstName='" + this.FirstName + "', LastName='" + this.LastName + "', Address='" + this.Address + "', Telno='" + this.Telno + "' WHERE PersonId='" + this.PersonId + "';", con);
        }
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            if (!existing)
            {

                retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else
            {
                retVal = -1;
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            throw er;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: You don't show any code where PersonId is actually set. *Is it* being set somewhere? Also, you should definitely look into using parameters for your queries.

Comment: One of your ifs appears to be wrong. You check if the PersonId is not null and if it is not null you make an insert instead of an update. Wouldn't the correct way of doing this is checking if the PersonId is null and them if it is null to run the insert? The else statement (the update one) only enters when PersonId is null that's why it's always returns null to you.

Comment: I agree with Rafael and Mahdionnet. out of curiosity why aren't you using Entity Framework? Youre life with queries will be far simpler. This is even more natural if you are using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Insert" portion you've checked that the Person Id shouldn't be NULL and in the "Update" portion you've assumed that it should be NULL?
I think it should be in the reverse order:

- when the user wants to insert a new person, he/she doesn't have the person's ID; The system gives the user a fresh and unique ID (The way you define it to do)
- When user wants to update a person's info he/she should have the person's ID to do so, so it shouldn't be NULL

something like this (not a good example, just a quick change in your code):

```
if (this._PersonId == null)
    {
        existing = false;
        this._PersonId=NewPersonID();//a method to obtain a new PersonID
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BORROWER (PersonId, FirstName, LastName, Address, Telno, CategoryId) VALUES ('" + this._PersonId + "','" + this._FirstName + "','" + this._LastName + "','" + this._Address + "','" + this._Telno + "'," + _CategoryId + ");", con);
    }
    else
    {
        existing = true;
        cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE BORROWER set FirstName='" + this.FirstName + "', LastName='" + this.LastName + "', Address='" + this.Address + "', Telno='" + this.Telno + "' WHERE PersonId='" + this.PersonId + "';", con);
    }
```

Hope it settles the situation!